# What does $\ln(\ln(x))$ simplify to?

Tags: calculus, notation

What does $\ln(\ln(x))$ simplify to?

First instinct was to write $\ln^2x$, but that looked odd, because $\ln(\ln(x))$ is not the same as $\ln(x)\ln(x)$ or $(\ln(x))^2$.

Or is it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the following figure:

[image]

The blue curve is $y = \log x$ (or $\ln x$ for those of you who like to use "ln" instead of "log").  The red curve is $y = (\log x)^2$, which is sometimes written as $\log^2 x$, similar to how it is customary to write $\sin^2 x$ for $(\sin x)^2$.  The yellow curve is $y = \log(\log x)$, which does not simplify, and there is generally no standardized shorthand for this expression, which we can regard as a **composition** of the logarithm with itself.  Sometimes, when repeated composition is desired, it might be written as $$f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f(x) = f^n(x)$$ but this is very confusing, since this is not what we mean when we write $\sin^n x$, as $\sin(\sin(\sin(\cdots(\sin x)\cdots)))$ is quite a different thing.

Some authors might use alternative notations; e.g., $f^{(n)}(x)$ or $f^{[n]}(x)$ to denote $n$-fold compositions, but this could also be confused with higher-order derivatives.  Bottom line:  it is always better to briefly **define** your notation clearly if there is any doubt as to whether it is standard usage, since it's better to be understood if a bit wordy (like this post) instead of terse and opaque.

Comment: Thx for the visualization definitely illuminated the issue

Comment: I like $f^{\circ2}$ as a notation for iterated composition that is unlikely to conflict with other notation.

Answer (score 4):

$\ln^2 x$ *ought* to mean $\ln\ln x$ but some people write $\ln^2 x$ when they mean $(\ln x)^2$.  I would avoid the notation unless I explain at the outset what I mean by it.  In either case it does *not* mean $\ln(x^2)$, which is the same as $2\ln x$.

Gauss wrote that $\sin^2 x$ ought to mean $\sin\sin x$ rather than $(\sin x)^2$.  But the latter meaning has become standard.

Comment: $$2\in x{}{}{}?$$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : Typo: I had \in where I needed \ln. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't simplify to anything nice. $\ln(\ln (x))$ is the composition of $\ln (x)$ with itself.

The rule you're talking about is  $\ln x+\ln y = \ln (xy)$.

Also, most of the times I've seen "$\ln^2(x)$", this is meant to denote $\ln(x)\cdot\ln(x)=(\ln(x))^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$ln(ln(x))$ is indeed not the same as $ln(x)*ln(x)$, but it is the same as $(ln \circ ln)(x)$ where $\circ$ denotes composition. Composition is also a kind of multiplication (see group theory) so it makes sense to write it as $ln^2$. Just always check to what kind of a multiplication an exponent refers.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(\ln(x))$ does not, in fact, simplify. You can write it as "$\ln^2(x)$" - I think that would be understood the right way - but beyond that, there's nothing really you can do. (Note that indeed $\ln(\ln(x))\not=(\ln(x))^2$ - for example, $\ln(\ln(e))=\ln(1)=0$, but $(\ln(e))^2=1$.)

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729 No, $(\ln e)^2=(1)^2=1$.

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729 $(\ln e)^2 = 1^2 = 1$ whereas $\ln (e^2) = 2$

Comment: I would be careful writing $\ln(\ln(x))$ as $\ln^2(x)$; I would interpret this in the same way as $\sin^2(x)$, $(\ln(x))^2$.

Comment: @AlexS but you would interpret $sin^{-1}(x)$ as the inverse sine right? That means you regard the exponent as refering to composition. It's all correct notation and all confusing ;)

Comment: @JensRenders Well, it much more common to use $\sin^{-1}$ for the inverse, as $\frac {1}{\sin x}$ has a proper name (a fair point would be that there's $\arcsin$ too, but o well).

Comment: @JensRenders Yes it is confusing, and all just depends on context. In my dynamical systems class, it means composition, when I teach calculus, it means exponentiation, and in my functional analysis class, it can mean either or both!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD you are right about it's commoness but I always care much more about correctness :)

Comment: @JensRenders well, I'm guessing that in any serious writing, the author would clarify the notation beforehand.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Indeed, that is certainly the way to deal with this stuff